# a question about codes of dynamic menus in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, menu

I upload the snaps of the codes to Flickr.com.

Here is the html part:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/59919989@N08/5470586866/

Here is the JavaScript part:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/59919989@N08/5470587034/

Could someone tell me what is the meaning of the circled part? What does it do?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The code in this question is taken from *JavaScript & Ajax for the Web, Visual QuickStart Guide, 7th Edition*. I am the primary author of the book. Since the code is clearly explained, line by line, in the book, I conclude that you are a student who is asking other people to do your homework for you. That's academically lazy, at best, and at the least is just not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it gets the element with the id named "months" and in your html it shows that it is the select tag. it then sets the selected item by default using selectedIndex. 0 means the first item in your options list which is "Month"

also next time, please put your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is straight out of *JavaScript & Ajax for the Web: Visual QuickStart Guide, 7th edition*<sup>1</sup>, what in particular are you having trouble with in the (line-by-line) explanation on pages 164-166?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Co-written by me, btw.</sub>